# Cucumber scenario embed twice results in two screenshoots taken with same filename

Tags: selenium, cucumber, screenshot, scenarios, selenide

scenario.embed is used to embed two different screen-shots. One screen shot of the topmost area of the browser, and one of the bottommost.
However screen-shots yields the same file name in cucumber report thus only two identical screen-shots are seen in report.

Taking only one screen-shot works fine to embed in cucumber report. However this is the first attempt to include two (2) screen-shots.  It has not worked before with two screen-shots.
pom.xml  ; 
cucumber-reporting 3.16.0, cucumber-java 1.2.5, java 1.8
jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin

```java
if (scenario.isFailed()) {             
try {
   System.out.println("Taking screenshot 1");
   byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) getWebDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
   scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
   System.out.println("Screenshot 1 taken");

   System.out.println("Taking screenshot 2");
   getWebDriver().manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0,0));
   byte[] screenshot2 = ((TakesScreenshot) getWebDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
   scenario.embed(screenshot2, "image/png");
   System.out.println("Screenshot 2 taken");



Expected
No error message. Cucumber report to include two different screenshots with different filename.

Actual
No error message. Cucumber report to include two same screenshots with same filename.

Resulting cucumber-html-reports/report-feature_3750966460.html :


      <a>Attachment 1 (png)</a>
      <a href="embeddings/embedding_-2088059111.png" download target="_blank">
        <span class="download-button glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="embedding-9" class="collapse collapsable-details">
      <div class="embedding-content">
        <img src="embeddings/embedding_-2088059111.png">
      </div>
    . . .
      <a>Attachment 2 (png)</a>
      <a href="embeddings/embedding_-2088059111.png" download target="_blank">
        <span class="download-button glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="embedding-10" class="collapse collapsable-details">
      <div class="embedding-content">
        <img src="embeddings/embedding_-2088059111.png">
      </div>
```

Comment: As i understand, u r trying to attach 2 images 1 for topmost and other 1 for bottom part. we could also take 1 full image of the web page, that would be easier for you right.

Comment: You should report this as a bug to `jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin`.

Comment: @TheSociety I have tried it. It did not take a picture (screenshot) of the whole logical screen.
It appears that when taking one screenshot it’s only the visible part, bottom-most (scrolled into) part, of the much larger (taller) logical screen (x,y -wise) that is included in the screenshot? Any hints how I get the whole logical screen will be much appreciated. I guess that's more of a selenium library question than cucumber.
( So my second attempt to resolve the first issue was to set the position to (0,0) x, y and take a second screenshot from that topmost part of the logical screen. )

Answer (score 0):

Try this code logic:

```
if (scenario.isFailed()) {
    //take screenshot
    String screenshotName =scenario.getName().replaceAll("", "_");
    byte[] sourcepath =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    scenario.attach(sourcepath, "image/png", screenshotName);
}
```